# WHy to use prototype outside of function

Tags: javascript

I was learning prototypes in JS and if you look at the code below

```
function Car(){
this.brand="BMW";
}

Car.prototype.drive = function(){
console.log(brand);
}
```

the question is WHY to declare Car.prototype.drive outside of the function? INSTEAD OF INSIDE THE FUNCTION? **The second question** is it is suggested not to use since "_proto__" was deprecated but WHY?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript engine implicitly adds a `prototype` property to the function `Car`.
Try `console.dir(Car)` and you can see prototype property being attached to this function.

This `prototype` is actually an object (called as `prototype object`), where you can add properties and methods to a function. In your sample code, you are adding a `drive` method to your function `Car`.

So, the answer to your question is, since `prototype object` is not part of the actualy function code, but an object attached as property to the `Car` function, you need to write it outside the function.

Note: The ES6 version of writing your sample code would be:

```
class Car() {
  this.brand = "BMW";
  drive () {
    console.log('brand`);
  }
}
```

This class pattern is just syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. It is recommended to use this pattern over prototype based pattern.

Answer to your second question:
`__proto__` is deprecated in favor of `Object.getPrototypeOf / Object.setPrototypeOf`. It is recommended to not use it since it's a slow operation and can mess things up. read more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).